# renaming factor levels in base R

Tags: r

First I need to make the setosas male and the versicolors and virginica female. Then I need to swap these males and females. And I need to connect them to the loop

```
Burak=iris
sehir= c("zonguldak","bilecik","samsun","sinop","gender")
for ( i in 1:ncol(Burak)) {
   colnames(Burak)[i] = sehir[i]
  
   
}
head(Burak)



levels(iris$Species) <- c(levels(iris$Species), "female")
iris$Species[iris$Species == 'virginica'] <- 'female'

levels(iris$Species) <- c(levels(iris$Species), "male")
iris$Species[iris$Species == 'setosa'] <- 'male'

levels(iris$Species) <- c(levels(iris$Species), "female")
iris$Species[iris$Species == 'versicolor'] <- 'female'
```

Comment: Hello, Halil. Can you add more detail in your question? What do you mean with "change function name" and with "connect them to the loop"?

Comment: My english not good sorry about that :D . ı change name virginica,setosa and versicolor. 
I made the names male and female. Let's say I misspelled genders after this step. I have to make men women and women men again. but i am trying to do this with if command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to understand how to assign levels to a factor.

To change the "names" of your factor levels, just assign the "new names" as factor levels in the order needed.

When you check the "sequence" of the original factor levels, you get:

```
levels(Burak$gender)
[1] "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica"
```

For demonstration purposes, let's add a new column and "overwrite" the factor levels in the order you need them.

```
Burak$gender2 <- Burak$gender
levels(Burak$gender2) <- c("male","female","female")
```

Alternatively, you can use a more verbose assignment using a list.

```
Burak$gender3 <- Burak$gender 
levels(Burak$gender3) <- list(male = "setosa", female = "versicolor", female = "virginica")
```